# Ошибка кодировки csv python

Tags: python

Подскажите, в чем проблема с кодировкой при записи русских и английских слов в csv файл?
Пишу код в пайчарме.
После запуска смотрю файл в самом пайчарме (файл сохраняется там где и проект) и в csv отображается все правильно, без "каракулей"
Однако если зайти в проводник и открыть csv файл в excel'e, то слова на английском - записаны как нужно, а на месте русских слов - почему-то каракули.\

Указал кодировку utf-8, но безрезультатно.
Код:

```
import csv

words = ['stolb', 'столб', 'stolb3', 'привет']

with open('csvfile.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as csvf:
    write_method = csv.writer(csvf, delimiter=';')
    write_method.writerow(words)
```

Просмотр csv файла в пайчарме:

```
stolb   столб   stolb3  привет
```

Просмотр файла в excel'e:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скажите, как решить проблему с кодировкой?

Comment: винды небось 1251 требуют

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-individual-file-encoding.html#edit

Comment: @splash58 работает, спасибо. Зачем тогда вообще везде пишут кодировку utf-8, если 1251 - универсальна и всегда работает?

Comment: неправда ваша.  Это пережитки микрософтовских программ в винде. А во вторых, с ней очень много проблем, особенно, если у вас в тексте не только буквы, а еще и какие-то дополнительные  символы . Тоже длинное тире или кавычки елочки, например